# separation of variables for boundary problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble understanding how to use separation of variable method on the following problem:

$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{du}{dy}; u(0,y)=e^y +e^{-2y}$

and the solution is $u(t,y) = e^{t+y}+e^{-2(t+y)}$

I converted the initial equation into $\frac{T'}{T}=\frac{Y'}{Y}$ but got stuck, so I tried using the fact that $u(0,y) = T(0)Y(y)$ but I am not sure how to utilize that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:  The point of separation of variables is that if $T$ is a function only of $t$ and $Y$ is only a function of $y$, then
$$
\frac{T'}{T} = \frac{Y'}{Y} = k
$$
where $k$ is a constant.  Based on that, what are the solutions $T_k(t)$ and $Y_k(y)$ for a given value of $k$?

This gives you a whole class of solutions $u_k(t,y) = T_k(t) Y_k(y)$.  You can then add two or more of these solutions together (with different $k$ values) to get another solution.  The solution you want is the one that satisfies the initial conditions $u(0,y) = e^y + e^{-2y}$.  Look at what each one of your individual solutions $u_k(t,y)$ are doing at $t = 0$;  this should tell you what combination of $u_k$'s you need to use to satisfy the initial conditions.

Comment: So $T(t)$ and $Y(y)$ will always be of the same form correct?

Comment: @CuriousStudent:  In this case, yes, since the equations satisfied by $T$ and $Y$ are identical.  This won't always be the case for other ODEs, though.